# Selected by type in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen the following code somewhere, used to select object by type

```
SELECT  MyObj.uxObj FROM MyObj WHERE iObjType = :A<int,in>
```

I know ':A' is some kind of fillchar, but it's not working in SQL Server. How to fix it?

Comment: you want this query to run in SQL server ?

Comment: @AshutoshArya Arya  Ye,and I wonder what kind of sql allows such code.

Comment: Fillchar ':A<int,in>' can be used in OTLV4.0.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps
`DECLARE @v varchar(1) = 'a'

Select *

From (

  Select 'a' as object_type

  Union all

  Select 'b' as object_type

  ) x

Where x.object_type = @v`

Comment: Thanks, but using a fillchar maybe could select different fields with same property in just a line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select certain types of column you can use

```
select * from information_schema.columns where data_type = 'int'
```